# list all products and the total sales in dollars for each product. List products in order from highest total sales to lowest

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to get the price to go in dollar amount in SQLite, I have the SQL code but cant figure out how to get it to format to $ amount.

```
 SELECT product, SUM(price) as Total_Price from sales group by product order by SUM(Price) DESC;
```

I have tried using the print function with no luck, and haven seen another way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are looking for just:

```
SELECT product, PRINTF('$%,d', SUM(price)) as Total_Price from sales group by product order by SUM(Price) DESC;
```

or possibly `'$%.2f'` (You can't have both commas and cents.)

Note that PRINTF was renamed to FORMAT in sqlite 3.38, but the older name PRINTF still works.

Comment: ok so why isn't that function a saved item to be used in SQLite?

Comment: no idea what a saved item is.

Comment: yes that was what i was looking for thank you, still new to SQL.